# Shifting column header and column value down by n rows

Tags: python, pandas

This is my data set and my starting row is Name onwards. How do I put the brand column down along with the name, address... row? I cannot drop the row above the starting row because I need it for extraction.

```
2        3      4      5      6       7     ...    Brand
A        B     nan    nan    nan     nan    ...     nike
Nan      B     nan    nan     C      nan    ...     nike
Nan      B     nan    nan     C      nan    ...     nike
AA       B     nan    nan     C      nan    ...     Adidas
Name  Address  Type   Size   Comment Grade  ...     Adidas
John    ggg    sports  8     Nil      A     ....    Adidas
```

This is the result I want:

```
2        3      4      5      6       7     ...    
A        B     nan    nan    nan     nan    ...     
Nan      B     nan    nan     C      nan    ...     
Nan      B     nan    nan     C      nan    ...     
AA       B     nan    nan     C      nan    ...     
Name  Address  Type   Size   Comment Grade  ...     Brand
John    ggg    sports  8     Nil      A     ....    Nike
John    ggg    sports  9     Nil      B     ....    Nike
Mary    ggg    sports  6     Nil      A     ....    Adidas
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
df['Brand'] = df['Brand'].shift(df['2'].str.contains('Name').idxmax()+1)
df.at[df['2'].str.contains('Name').idxmax(), 'Brand'] = 'Brand'
print(df)
```

**Output**

```
    2   3     4        5      6     7   ...     Brand
0   A   B   NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     ...     NaN
1   Nan     B   NaN     NaN     C   NaN     ...     NaN
2   Nan     B   NaN     NaN     C   NaN     ...     NaN
3   AA  B   NaN     NaN     C   NaN     ...     NaN
4   Name    Address     Type    Size    Comment     Grade   ...     Brand
5   John    ggg     sports  8   Nil     A   ....    nike
```